# Chord of dynamically created group not called

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, chord

Recently found out about Celery's `task.replace` and trying to harness its power I've come across a puzzling situation, which according to Celery's documentation (and the assorted Pull-Requests/SO questions laying around the internet) - should work.
Let's say I have the following code:

```
from celery import Celery, group
app = Celery(broker='pyamqp://', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task
def to_char(seq):
    return map(chr, seq)

@app.task
def flatten(seqs):
    final = list()
    for seq in seqs:
        final.extend(seq)
    return final

@app.task(bind=True)
def combine(self):
    sig = group([to_char.s([97]), to_char.s([98, 98])]) | flatten.s()
    raise self.replace(sig)
```

I obviously simplifed the problem a bit - but even in this simple case, when I call `combine.delay().get()` I expect to receive `[a, b, b]`.
Instead of getting a result the call to `get()` hangs indefinitely and looking over the worker logs - I can see both calls to `to_char` being received & completing successfully BUT no call to `flatten`.

When I try to execute it individually (in the Python console, for example) it works and returns the expected results, so the problem is definitely in my understanding of the mechanics of `task.replace`:

```
g = group([to_char.s([97]), to_char.s([98, 98])])
c = g | flatten.s()
c.delay().get() # -> [a, b, b]
```

Many thanks for whoever can shed some light on the problem!